# unit testing with pytest parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following test code:

```
class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('item', [5,4,10])
    def test_valid_range(self, item):
        self.assertTrue(1 <= item <= 1000)
```

This is not my real test this is just a minimal reproduce example.

I need to parameterised only the input which is checked against the same code.

For some reason this doesn't work I always get:

```
 TypeError: test_valid_range() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does `@pytest.mark.parametrize('item', [(5,),(4,),(10,)])` work perhaps (don't have time to test it myself atm)

Comment: @AndrewAllaire no, same error

Comment: Wait a minute...you are mixing unittest with pytest? I did not know one could do that.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire You can't. :-) At least not in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` on `unittest.TestCase methods`. PyTest has no way to pass in the parameter.

Just do:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('item', [5,4,10])
def test_valid_range(item):
    self.assertTrue(1 <= item <= 1000)
```

Comment: I have many other tests in the class with setups and stuff that I don't want to touch. So if I need parameterised I need to use https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/ ?

Comment: @Slava If you are already using nose tests, sure. Otherwise it's probably better to not parameterize the test, and just do a loop in the test function over all the parameters. If you need to run setUp for each parameter value, then it gets complicated.